# JQuery facebook subscribe plugin mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, plugins, mouseevent

I'm trying to execute a script after a user clicks the Facebook subscribe plugin but when I click it, the event isn't firing.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).mousedown(function(){
   alert("clicked");
   });
   </script>
```

it works when I click everything but the subscribe button itself.

help? 
Thanks!

Comment: What version of the subscribe button are you using? Is the iframe version as that might be your issue

Comment: I tried all of them (HTML5,FBXML,IFRAME) but they all eventually create an iframe. I also tried $(window) but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's not possible for now...

This might answer your question : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10403703/handling-a-click-on-facebooks-subscribe-button

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to monitor the mouse coordinates while it's over an iframe?